# javascript syntax $.tzPOST

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following segment js code, but I can't understand `$.tzPOST`.

```
$.tzPOST('login',$(this).serialize(),function(r){
    working = false;

    if(r.error){
        chat.displayError(r.error);
    }
    else chat.login(r.name,r.gravatar);
});
```

What does `$.tzPOST` mean?

Thanks you so much !

Comment: That is called a _function_ (an object method in this case). `tzPOST` is static _method_ of the `$` object. If you can't understand it then you should learn basics of JavaScript.

Comment: maybe a jquery-plugin has been installed in the project, but of course it is used as a _function_, as said by @Vohuman

Comment: Have you searched your javascript code, if the function tzPost is defined somewhere ? The function seems to execute a POST-Call to the 'login' uri, by posting $(this).serialize() as data and on server response the function(r) is executed. But this is just a guess, because tzPOST is not a known framework function.

Comment: thanks for answers . I understood

Answer (score -1):

I think you're referring to [this tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/10/ajax-web-chat-css-jquery/) about a live webchat.

Rboe guessed right that tzPOST is a custom function that was added to $ (jQuery) object. The tutorial provides the source for both tzPOST and tzGET functions on the same page (use CTRL+F there to find it quickly), here they are:

```
// Custom GET & POST wrappers:
$.tzPOST = function(action,data,callback){
    $.post('php/ajax.php?action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}

$.tzGET = function(action,data,callback){
    $.get('php/ajax.php?action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}
```

It just makes POST and GET requests code shorter and therefore easier to read and maintain. For example, if you change the name or location of your ajax.php file you'd just need to change the path in these 2 functions instead of changing it in every AJAX request. With the standard way your function would look like this:

```
$.post('php/ajax.php?action=login', $(this).serialize(), function(r) {
    working = false;

    if(r.error){
        chat.displayError(r.error);
    }else {
        chat.login(r.name,r.gravatar);
    }
}, 'json');
```

So the difference is small.

Comment: If you downvote, please leave a comment telling why.